# How to get the data from React Context Consumer outside the render

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am using the new React Context API and I need to get the Consumer data from the Context.Consumer variable and not using it inside the render method. Is there anyway that I can achieve this?

For examplify what I want:

```
console.log(Context.Consumer.value);
```

What I tested so far: the above example, tested Context.Consumer currentValue and other variables that Context Consumer has, tried to execute Context.Consumer() as a function and none worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: I tested a similar approach, there's a `_currentValue` and `_defaultValue` members inside a consumer, but accessing `Context.Consumer._currentValue.value` always returns the default value or undefined if not properly inited.

Comment: I create a HOC https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-context-consumer-hoc that achieves this by wrapping your component prior to exporting it. It might NOT be what you are looking for, but I want to put it here because this is where I ended up the first time I had this issue.

Comment: Do have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72467494/unable-to-run-the-function-from-the-context

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve this in functional components by with [`useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) Hook.

You just need to import the Context from the file you initialised it in. In this case, `DBContext`.

```js
 const contextValue = useContext(DBContext);
```

Answer (score 33):

## Update

As of **React v16.6.0**, you can use the context API like:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
       console.log(this.context);
    }
    render() {
       // render part here
       // use context with this.context
    }
}
App.contextType = CustomContext
```

However, the component can only access a single context. In order to use multiple context values, use the render prop pattern. More about [Class.contextType](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype).

If you are using the experimental [public class fields syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/), you can use a **static** class field to initialize your `contextType`:

```js
class MyClass extends React.Component {
  static contextType = MyContext;
  render() {
    let value = this.context;
    /* render something based on the value */
  }
}
```

## Render Prop Pattern

When what I understand from the question, to use context inside your component but outside of the render, create a HOC to wrap the component:

```
const WithContext = (Component) => {
  return (props) => (
      <CustomContext.Consumer>
           {value =>  <Component {...props} value={value} />}
      </CustomContext.Consumer>
  )
}
```

and then use it:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
       console.log(this.props.value);
    }
    render() {
       // render part here
    }
}
export default WithContext(App);
```

Comment: This is more or less the official question from https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#accessing-context-in-lifecycle-methods

However I found this solution a lot complex and boilerplate than old `this.context` of React 15.

Comment: @LucaFabbri, from version 16.6.0 version of React onwards, the context API can be used using `this.context` so no more BoilerPlate to it

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, I don't know why the 16.6+ `App.contextType = CustomContext`didn't work for me. It didn't make anything. And the `static contextType` only works when you have 1 context. However, the WithContext worked like a charm! Claps to you.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, `static contextType = MyContext;` what's MyContext ?

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine MyContext is the context you create using React.createContext

Answer (score 2):

You can via an unsupported getter:

```
YourContext._currentValue
```

Note that it only works during render, not in an async function or other lifecycle events.

Answer (score 2):

For the @wertzguy solution to work, you need to be sure that your store is defined like this:

```
// store.js
import React from 'react';

let user = {};
const UserContext = React.createContext({
  user,
  setUser: () => null
});

export { UserContext };
```

Then you can do

```
import { UserContext } from 'store';

console.log(UserContext._currentValue.user);
```

Comment: How did anyone discover this `._currentValue`?  Typescript doesn't like it and I can't find it when I click into the `Context` code... just shows interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it can be achieved.

```
 class BasElement extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.context);
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

const Element = () => (
  <Context.Consumer>
    {context =>
      <BaseMapElement context={context} />
    }
  </Context.Consumer>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code from what I was trying for myself. Hope it helps.

```
import React from 'react';

const ThemeContext = React.createContext('light');

class ThemeContextComponent extends React.Component {
  static contextType = ThemeContext;
  render() {
    return <div>Testing the {this.context} </div>;
  }
}

function useTask(context) {
  return React.useContext(context);
}

function ThemeFunctionUseContextComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      ThemeFunctionUseContextComponent: Testing the {useTask(ThemeContext)}{' '}
    </div>
  );
}

function ThemeFunctionContextComponent(props) {
  var contextType = ThemeContext;
  return (
    <div>
      ThemeFunctionContextComponent: Testing the context <br /> current Value: {contextType._currentValue}, <br />{' '}
      current value 2: {contextType._currentValue2}, <br /> default value:{' '}
      {contextType._defaultValue} <br /> Global Name: {contextType._globalName}{' '}
      <br /> ThreadCount: {contextType._threadCount}{' '}
    </div>
  );
}

function ThemeFunctionUseContextComponent(props) {
  var contextType = React.useContext(ThemeContext);
  return (
    <div>ThemeFunctionUseContextComponent: Testing the context {contextType} </div>
  );
}

function WithContext(Component) {
  return (props) => (
    <ThemeContext.Consumer>
      {(value) => <Component {...props} context={value} />}
    </ThemeContext.Consumer>
  )
}

function ThemeFunctionUseContextTwoComponent(props) {
  return <div>ThemeFunctionUseContextTwoComponent: Testing the context={props.context} </div>;
}

var ThemeFunctionUseContextThreeComponent = WithContext(
  ThemeFunctionUseContextTwoComponent
);

function ThemeComponent(props) {
  return <div>ThemeComponent: Testing the {props.theme} </div>;
}

class RectorComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>RectorComponent: Testing this {this.props.theme} </div>;
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello Starter!</h1>

      <ThemeComponent theme="dark" />
      <br />
      <RectorComponent theme="dark" />
      <br />
      <ThemeContext.Provider value="dark">
        <ThemeContextComponent />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
      <br />
      <ThemeContext.Provider value="dark">
        <ThemeFunctionContextComponent />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
      <br />
      <ThemeContext.Provider value="dark">
        <ThemeFunctionUseContextThreeComponent />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
      <br/>

      <ThemeContext.Provider value="dark">
        <ThemeFunctionUseContextComponent />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
      <br />

    </div>
  );
}
```

I am not sure of side effects of following code usage:

```
function ElementWithContextFunctionPattern(Component) {
  return ((props) => (
    <ThemeContext.Consumer>
      {(context) => (
        <ThemeFunctionUseContextTwoComponent {...props} context={context} />
      )}
    </ThemeContext.Consumer>
  ))();
}
```

It can be used as :

```
export default function App() {
  return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider value="dark">
        <ElementWithContextFunctionPattern />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Also have a look at this:
[Unable to run the function from the context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72467494/unable-to-run-the-function-from-the-context)