# setting state after calling api in react

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I have tried numerous ways to set state but for some reason, the state never gets updated.this is the JSON data that I want my state to change to

```
export class Provider extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: [],
    profileinfo: {},
    dispatch: action => this.setState(state => reducer(state, action))
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/login").then(response =>
      response
        .json()
        .then(data => this.setState({ profileinfo: data.firstname }))
    );
    console.log(this.state.profileinfo);
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include the data in text format instead of as an image.

Comment: you have to put you componentDidMount() with a condition comparing old state/props with new one. then you will avoid infinite loop

Comment: The promise gets resolved?

Comment: no it doesn't get resolved

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is asynchronous. Your console log probably triggers before the state got updated. If you want to see the result after the `setState` call, do it this way:

```
data => this.setState({ profileinfo: data.firstname }, () => {
  console.log(this.state);
});
```

Comment: the profile info still doesn't get updated as the profile info is stored in context api ,I am trying to fetch the value of it

Comment: So actually, your fetch doesn't work and you are not getting the data?

Comment: If your profile info is stored inside the context, you don't fetch it's value. You use context ```Provider``` and ```Consumer``` to access the values. Read about it here:https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49870973/6036881

Comment: Yes for that i need to set the state so that i can access the value from another component .As of now it returns undefined when I try to print the value