# Class based Context.Provider and UseContext working example

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, use-context

I came across a scenario wherein i was making an app entirely using React hooks.

I had to use certain NPM libraries in the app which were not hooks compatible. To avoid prop drilling, i plan to use useContext. Since some of my components which were using non-hooks compatible npm libraries had to be class based.

Using React-context api along with useContext was one of the sensible recourse.

Following is a very basic example for any-one trying to use useContext as Context consumer along with Context Provider.

[CODE SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-river-qlkzk?file=/src/UseContextConsumer.js)

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: This is more of a sharing info rather than posting a question. The sandbox shows a basic example of useContext working with React context API. Like how i struggled for a day to get it working, this might be useful for someone.

Comment: is it related to this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62464615/difference-between-class-contexttype-and-context-consumer-with-working-example - that might be a better place to put it? easier for people to find